# Javascript focused control

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

Is there any way I can determine the currently focused control on a web page? I wish to save the focused control before my ajax callback and restore it afterwards.

Can this be easily determined?

Thanks,

AJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
document.activeElement
```

This has not been officially standardized yet ([it will be in HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.activeElement)), but most, if not all, modern browsers support it. It started in [Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533065.aspx) so all versions of IE will support it. Firefox has supported it since FF3. Chrome also supports it and I assume Safari does as well.

Answer (score 1):

Many browsers now support `document.activeElement`.

Works in:

- Firefox
- IE 6,7,8
- Chrome
- Safari
- Opera

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery you can solve this with the http://plugins.jquery.com/project/focused plugin

```
// elm is the DOM Element owning the focus or null if no
// DOM Element has the focus
var elm = jQuery.focused();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `document.activeElement`.